# Prevent text highlight inside Chrome when double-clicking

Tags: html, css

Inside Chrome when I tap on the SVG in the below example a few times, the bottom text becomes highlighted. It doesn’t do it in firefox though.

Is there a way to prevent that from happening? Is there code I could add that would prevent it from happening, or could this be a bug or something inside Chrome?

Fiddl:
https://jsfiddle.net/xeqtcp5k/77/

[image]

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  background: #000000;
}

.outer {
  display: table;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.tcell {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.wrape {
  position: relative;
  width: 266px;
  height: 174px;
  overflow: hidden;
  background: #000000;
  border-radius: 25px;
}

.nav {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
}

.nav li {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  float: left;
}

.wrape .nav li a {
  float: left;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  margin: 0 4px 12px 0;
  color: transparent;
  background: #000000;
  border: 3px solid #0059dd;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.wrape .nav li:nth-of-type(n+11) a {
  margin: 0 4px 0 0;
}

.wrape .nav li:nth-of-type(5n) a {
  margin-right: 0;
}

.wrape .nav li:nth-of-type(8) a {
  opacity: 0;
  border: none;
  background: none;
}

.wrape .nav li:nth-of-type(1) a {
  border-top-left-radius: 25px;
}

.wrape .nav li:nth-of-type(5) a {
  border-top-right-radius: 25px;
}

.link {
  fill: #0059dd;
}

.wrape .nav li:nth-of-type(11) a {
  border-bottom-left-radius: 25px;
}

.wrape .nav li:nth-of-type(15) a {
  border-bottom-right-radius: 25px;
}

.btn {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: auto;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background: #000000;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.btn .play,
.btn .pause {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 6px;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  fill: #0059dd;
  margin: auto;
}

.btn .pause {
  left: 0;
}

.pause {
  display: none;
}

.is-playing .play {
  display: none;
}

.is-playing .pause {
  display: block;
}

.label {
  font-size: 22px;
  color: #0059dd;
  font-family: "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
}

.info {
  display: table-cell;
  white-space: nowrap;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.input {
  font-size: 22px;
  width: 200px;
  margin-top: 40px;
  background: #000000;
  color: #0059dd;
}

.sent {
  font-size: 22px;
  background: black;
  color: #0059dd;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-family: "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
}

.input:focus {
  outline: none;
}

.sent:focus {
  outline: none;
}

.wrap  p{
  display: table;
  margin: 22px auto 0;
  background: green;
  width: 300px;
  /*height: 100%; remove*/
  border: 1px solid red;
  font-weight: 900;
  font-style: normal;
  font-size: 22px;
  font-family: "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
  padding: 5px;
  color: #0059dd;
}
```

```html
<div class='outer'>
  <div class='tcell'>
    <audio autoplay id="player"></audio>
    <div class="wrape">
      <ul class="nav">
        <li>
          <a href="" target="_blank">
            <svg class="link" width="44" height="44" viewbox="-6 -6 35 35">
              <path d="M22 24h-20v-24h14l6 6v18zm-7-23h-12v22h18v-16h-6v-6zm3 15v1h-12v-1h12zm0-3v1h-12v-1h12zm0-3v1h-12v-1h12zm-2-4h4.586l-4.586-4.586v4.586z"/>
            </svg>
          </a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="" target="_blank">
            <svg class="link" width="44" height="44" viewbox="-6 -6 35 35">
              <path d="M22 24h-20v-24h14l6 6v18zm-7-23h-12v22h18v-16h-6v-6zm3 15v1h-12v-1h12zm0-3v1h-12v-1h12zm0-3v1h-12v-1h12zm-2-4h4.586l-4.586-4.586v4.586z"/>
            </svg>
          </a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="" target="_blank">
            <svg class="link" width="44" height="44" viewbox="-6 -6 35 35">
              <path d="M22 24h-20v-24h14l6 6v18zm-7-23h-12v22h18v-16h-6v-6zm3 15v1h-12v-1h12zm0-3v1h-12v-1h12zm0-3v1h-12v-1h12zm-2-4h4.586l-4.586-4.586v4.586z"/>
            </svg>
          </a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="" target="_blank">
            <svg class="link" width="44" height="44" viewbox="-6 -6 35 35">
              <path d="M22 24h-20v-24h14l6 6v18zm-7-23h-12v22h18v-16h-6v-6zm3 15v1h-12v-1h12zm0-3v1h-12v-1h12zm0-3v1h-12v-1h12zm-2-4h4.586l-4.586-4.586v4.586z"/>
            </svg>
          </a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="" target="_blank">
            <svg class="link" width="44" height="44" viewbox="-6 -6 35 35">
              <path d="M22 24h-20v-24h14l6 6v18zm-7-23h-12v22h18v-16h-6v-6zm3 15v1h-12v-1h12zm0-3v1h-12v-1h12zm0-3v1h-12v-1h12zm-2-4h4.586l-4.586-4.586v4.586z"/>
            </svg>
          </a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="" target="_blank">
            <svg class="link" width="44" height="44" viewbox="-6 -6 35 35">
              <path d="M22 24h-20v-24h14l6 6v18zm-7-23h-12v22h18v-16h-6v-6zm3 15v1h-12v-1h12zm0-3v1h-12v-1h12zm0-3v1h-12v-1h12zm-2-4h4.586l-4.586-4.586v4.586z"/>
            </svg>
          </a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="" target="_blank">
            <svg class="link" width="44" height="44" viewbox="-6 -6 35 35">
              <path d="M22 24h-20v-24h14l6 6v18zm-7-23h-12v22h18v-16h-6v-6zm3 15v1h-12v-1h12zm0-3v1h-12v-1h12zm0-3v1h-12v-1h12zm-2-4h4.586l-4.586-4.586v4.586z"/>
            </svg>
          </a>
        </li>
        <li><a> Audio Player</a></li>
        <li>
          <a href="" target="_blank">
            <svg class="link" width="44" height="44" viewbox="-6 -6 35 35">
              <path d="M22 24h-20v-24h14l6 6v18zm-7-23h-12v22h18v-16h-6v-6zm3 15v1h-12v-1h12zm0-3v1h-12v-1h12zm0-3v1h-12v-1h12zm-2-4h4.586l-4.586-4.586v4.586z"/>
            </svg>
          </a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="" target="_blank">
            <svg class="link" width="44" height="44" viewbox="-6 -6 35 35">
              <path d="M22 24h-20v-24h14l6 6v18zm-7-23h-12v22h18v-16h-6v-6zm3 15v1h-12v-1h12zm0-3v1h-12v-1h12zm0-3v1h-12v-1h12zm-2-4h4.586l-4.586-4.586v4.586z"/>
            </svg>
          </a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="" target="_blank">
            <svg class="link" width="44" height="44" viewbox="-6 -6 35 35">
              <path d="M22 24h-20v-24h14l6 6v18zm-7-23h-12v22h18v-16h-6v-6zm3 15v1h-12v-1h12zm0-3v1h-12v-1h12zm0-3v1h-12v-1h12zm-2-4h4.586l-4.586-4.586v4.586z"/>
            </svg>
          </a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="" target="_blank">
            <svg class="link" width="44" height="44" viewbox="-6 -6 35 35">
              <path d="M22 24h-20v-24h14l6 6v18zm-7-23h-12v22h18v-16h-6v-6zm3 15v1h-12v-1h12zm0-3v1h-12v-1h12zm0-3v1h-12v-1h12zm-2-4h4.586l-4.586-4.586v4.586z"/>
            </svg>
          </a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="" target="_blank">
            <svg class="link" width="44" height="44" viewbox="-6 -6 35 35">
              <path d="M22 24h-20v-24h14l6 6v18zm-7-23h-12v22h18v-16h-6v-6zm3 15v1h-12v-1h12zm0-3v1h-12v-1h12zm0-3v1h-12v-1h12zm-2-4h4.586l-4.586-4.586v4.586z"/>
            </svg>
          </a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="" target="_blank">
            <svg class="link" width="44" height="44" viewbox="-6 -6 35 35">
              <path d="M22 24h-20v-24h14l6 6v18zm-7-23h-12v22h18v-16h-6v-6zm3 15v1h-12v-1h12zm0-3v1h-12v-1h12zm0-3v1h-12v-1h12zm-2-4h4.586l-4.586-4.586v4.586z"/>
            </svg>
          </a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="" target="_blank">
            <svg class="link" width="44" height="44" viewbox="-6 -6 35 35">
              <path d="M22 24h-20v-24h14l6 6v18zm-7-23h-12v22h18v-16h-6v-6zm3 15v1h-12v-1h12zm0-3v1h-12v-1h12zm0-3v1h-12v-1h12zm-2-4h4.586l-4.586-4.586v4.586z"/>
            </svg>
          </a>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <div id="button" class="btn">
        <svg class="play " height="40" viewbox="0 0 85 100" width="38">
          <title>Play</title>
          <path d="M81 44.6c5 3 5 7.8 0 10.8L9 98.7c-5 3-9 .7-9-5V6.3c0-5.7 4-8 9-5l72 43.3z">
          </path>
        </svg>
        <svg class="pause " height="40" viewbox="0 0 60 100" width="36">
          <title>Pause</title>
          <path d="M0 8c0-5 3-8 8-8s9 3 9 8v84c0 5-4 8-9 8s-8-3-8-8V8zm43 0c0-5 3-8 8-8s8 3 8 8v84c0 5-3 8-8 8s-8-3-8-8V8z">
          </path>
        </svg>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="info">
      <label class="label" for="input">Text</label>
      <input class="input" id="input" type="text" name="someNameHere" value="someValueHere" />
      <input class="sent" id="sent" type="submit" value="Set" />
    </div>
    <div class="wrap">
      <p> 
        Text, text, text, Text, text, text, Text, text, text, Text, text, text, Text, text, text
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option is to interrupt the double-click event on the object, it won't interfere with single clicks:

([jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/2tfbLqd4/))

```
document.getElementById('button').addEventListener('mousedown', function (event) {
  if (event.detail > 1) {
    event.preventDefault();
  }
}, false);
```

Comment: I added the rest of the javascript in here, then this piece would be added to the top of it, right? https://jsfiddle.net/xeqtcp5k/110/

Comment: @MichelleSmith The placement doesn't really matter, but looking at that I think it would make most sense to put it right before the line that contains `sent.addEventListener("click", function() {`, because you're already adding event listeners in that area.

Comment: Do you think using the CSS or Javascript method is better to use here?

Comment: I improved the code further here, is that better?  button.addEventListener("mousedown", function (evt) https://jsfiddle.net/xeqtcp5k/152/

Comment: @MichelleSmith Yep, that's more concise. There's no need to re-select the `button` element as in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a wrapper `div` and set the user select to none which will stop the text from highlighting.

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  background: #000000;
}

.outer {
  display: table;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.tcell {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.noSel {
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  -o-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
}

.wrape {
  position: relative;
  width: 266px;
  height: 174px;
  overflow: hidden;
  background: #000000;
  border-radius: 25px;
}

.nav {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
}

.nav li {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  float: left;
}

.wrape .nav li a {
  float: left;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  margin: 0 4px 12px 0;
  color: transparent;
  background: #000000;
  border: 3px solid #0059dd;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.wrape .nav li:nth-of-type(n+11) a {
  margin: 0 4px 0 0;
}

.wrape .nav li:nth-of-type(5n) a {
  margin-right: 0;
}

.wrape .nav li:nth-of-type(8) a {
  opacity: 0;
  border: none;
  background: none;
}

.wrape .nav li:nth-of-type(1) a {
  border-top-left-radius: 25px;
}

.wrape .nav li:nth-of-type(5) a {
  border-top-right-radius: 25px;
}

.link {
  fill: #0059dd;
}

.wrape .nav li:nth-of-type(11) a {
  border-bottom-left-radius: 25px;
}

.wrape .nav li:nth-of-type(15) a {
  border-bottom-right-radius: 25px;
}

.btn {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: auto;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background: #000000;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.btn .play,
.btn .pause {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 6px;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  fill: #0059dd;
  margin: auto;
}

.btn .pause {
  left: 0;
}

.pause {
  display: none;
}

.is-playing .play {
  display: none;
}

.is-playing .pause {
  display: block;
}

.label {
  font-size: 22px;
  color: #0059dd;
  font-family: "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
}

.info {
  display: table-cell;
  white-space: nowrap;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.input {
  font-size: 22px;
  width: 200px;
  margin-top: 40px;
  background: #000000;
  color: #0059dd;
}

.sent {
  font-size: 22px;
  background: black;
  color: #0059dd;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-family: "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
}

.input:focus {
  outline: none;
}

.sent:focus {
  outline: none;
}

.wrap p {
  display: table;
  margin: 22px auto 0;
  background: green;
  width: 300px;
  /*height: 100%; remove*/
  border: 1px solid red;
  font-weight: 900;
  font-style: normal;
  font-size: 22px;
  font-family: "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
  padding: 5px;
  color: #0059dd;
}
```

```html
<div class='outer'>
  <div class='tcell'>
    <audio autoplay id="player"></audio>
    <div class='noSel'>
      <div class="wrape">
        <ul class="nav">
          <li>
            <a href="" target="_blank">
              <svg class="link" width="44" height="44" viewbox="-6 -6 35 35">
              <path d="M22 24h-20v-24h14l6 6v18zm-7-23h-12v22h18v-16h-6v-6zm3 15v1h-12v-1h12zm0-3v1h-12v-1h12zm0-3v1h-12v-1h12zm-2-4h4.586l-4.586-4.586v4.586z"/>
            </svg>
            </a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="" target="_blank">
              <svg class="link" width="44" height="44" viewbox="-6 -6 35 35">
              <path d="M22 24h-20v-24h14l6 6v18zm-7-23h-12v22h18v-16h-6v-6zm3 15v1h-12v-1h12zm0-3v1h-12v-1h12zm0-3v1h-12v-1h12zm-2-4h4.586l-4.586-4.586v4.586z"/>
            </svg>
            </a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="" target="_blank">
              <svg class="link" width="44" height="44" viewbox="-6 -6 35 35">
              <path d="M22 24h-20v-24h14l6 6v18zm-7-23h-12v22h18v-16h-6v-6zm3 15v1h-12v-1h12zm0-3v1h-12v-1h12zm0-3v1h-12v-1h12zm-2-4h4.586l-4.586-4.586v4.586z"/>
            </svg>
            </a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="" target="_blank">
              <svg class="link" width="44" height="44" viewbox="-6 -6 35 35">
              <path d="M22 24h-20v-24h14l6 6v18zm-7-23h-12v22h18v-16h-6v-6zm3 15v1h-12v-1h12zm0-3v1h-12v-1h12zm0-3v1h-12v-1h12zm-2-4h4.586l-4.586-4.586v4.586z"/>
            </svg>
            </a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="" target="_blank">
              <svg class="link" width="44" height="44" viewbox="-6 -6 35 35">
              <path d="M22 24h-20v-24h14l6 6v18zm-7-23h-12v22h18v-16h-6v-6zm3 15v1h-12v-1h12zm0-3v1h-12v-1h12zm0-3v1h-12v-1h12zm-2-4h4.586l-4.586-4.586v4.586z"/>
            </svg>
            </a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="" target="_blank">
              <svg class="link" width="44" height="44" viewbox="-6 -6 35 35">
              <path d="M22 24h-20v-24h14l6 6v18zm-7-23h-12v22h18v-16h-6v-6zm3 15v1h-12v-1h12zm0-3v1h-12v-1h12zm0-3v1h-12v-1h12zm-2-4h4.586l-4.586-4.586v4.586z"/>
            </svg>
            </a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="" target="_blank">
              <svg class="link" width="44" height="44" viewbox="-6 -6 35 35">
              <path d="M22 24h-20v-24h14l6 6v18zm-7-23h-12v22h18v-16h-6v-6zm3 15v1h-12v-1h12zm0-3v1h-12v-1h12zm0-3v1h-12v-1h12zm-2-4h4.586l-4.586-4.586v4.586z"/>
            </svg>
            </a>
          </li>
          <li><a> Audio Player</a></li>
          <li>
            <a href="" target="_blank">
              <svg class="link" width="44" height="44" viewbox="-6 -6 35 35">
              <path d="M22 24h-20v-24h14l6 6v18zm-7-23h-12v22h18v-16h-6v-6zm3 15v1h-12v-1h12zm0-3v1h-12v-1h12zm0-3v1h-12v-1h12zm-2-4h4.586l-4.586-4.586v4.586z"/>
            </svg>
            </a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="" target="_blank">
              <svg class="link" width="44" height="44" viewbox="-6 -6 35 35">
              <path d="M22 24h-20v-24h14l6 6v18zm-7-23h-12v22h18v-16h-6v-6zm3 15v1h-12v-1h12zm0-3v1h-12v-1h12zm0-3v1h-12v-1h12zm-2-4h4.586l-4.586-4.586v4.586z"/>
            </svg>
            </a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="" target="_blank">
              <svg class="link" width="44" height="44" viewbox="-6 -6 35 35">
              <path d="M22 24h-20v-24h14l6 6v18zm-7-23h-12v22h18v-16h-6v-6zm3 15v1h-12v-1h12zm0-3v1h-12v-1h12zm0-3v1h-12v-1h12zm-2-4h4.586l-4.586-4.586v4.586z"/>
            </svg>
            </a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="" target="_blank">
              <svg class="link" width="44" height="44" viewbox="-6 -6 35 35">
              <path d="M22 24h-20v-24h14l6 6v18zm-7-23h-12v22h18v-16h-6v-6zm3 15v1h-12v-1h12zm0-3v1h-12v-1h12zm0-3v1h-12v-1h12zm-2-4h4.586l-4.586-4.586v4.586z"/>
            </svg>
            </a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="" target="_blank">
              <svg class="link" width="44" height="44" viewbox="-6 -6 35 35">
              <path d="M22 24h-20v-24h14l6 6v18zm-7-23h-12v22h18v-16h-6v-6zm3 15v1h-12v-1h12zm0-3v1h-12v-1h12zm0-3v1h-12v-1h12zm-2-4h4.586l-4.586-4.586v4.586z"/>
            </svg>
            </a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="" target="_blank">
              <svg class="link" width="44" height="44" viewbox="-6 -6 35 35">
              <path d="M22 24h-20v-24h14l6 6v18zm-7-23h-12v22h18v-16h-6v-6zm3 15v1h-12v-1h12zm0-3v1h-12v-1h12zm0-3v1h-12v-1h12zm-2-4h4.586l-4.586-4.586v4.586z"/>
            </svg>
            </a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="" target="_blank">
              <svg class="link" width="44" height="44" viewbox="-6 -6 35 35">
              <path d="M22 24h-20v-24h14l6 6v18zm-7-23h-12v22h18v-16h-6v-6zm3 15v1h-12v-1h12zm0-3v1h-12v-1h12zm0-3v1h-12v-1h12zm-2-4h4.586l-4.586-4.586v4.586z"/>
            </svg>
            </a>
          </li>
        </ul>
        <div id="button" class="btn">
          <svg class="play " height="40" viewbox="0 0 85 100" width="38">
          <title>Play</title>
          <path d="M81 44.6c5 3 5 7.8 0 10.8L9 98.7c-5 3-9 .7-9-5V6.3c0-5.7 4-8 9-5l72 43.3z">
          </path>
        </svg>
          <svg class="pause " height="40" viewbox="0 0 60 100" width="36">
          <title>Pause</title>
          <path d="M0 8c0-5 3-8 8-8s9 3 9 8v84c0 5-4 8-9 8s-8-3-8-8V8zm43 0c0-5 3-8 8-8s8 3 8 8v84c0 5-3 8-8 8s-8-3-8-8V8z">
          </path>
        </svg>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="info">
      <label class="label" for="input">Text</label>
      <input class="input" id="input" type="text" name="someNameHere" value="someValueHere" />
      <input class="sent" id="sent" type="submit" value="Set" />
    </div>
    <div class="wrap">
      <p>
        Text, text, text, Text, text, text, Text, text, text, Text, text, text, Text, text, text
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: The usability downside of this is that the user cannot select the text even if they explicitly wanted to, yes?

Comment: True. edited to allow that using a wrapper div thanks.